# Below c# code is not reading websites or webpage from given urls

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, c#-3.0

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;

        request.Proxy = null;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
        {
            html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

**The above code not able to read/download the following webpages:**
1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Payments_Interface
2) http://www.npci.org.in/UPI_Background.aspx

Comment: so what does it do? in what way is it not getting it, what is the response variable containing when it "doesnt"

Comment: If I know that, in what way it is not getting it, then why would  have I asked.

Comment: Well you should have been able to go to debug after getresponse and look at the response variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This may help you below code contains for both to get and post data:

```
public static string PostContent(this Uri url, string body, string contentType = null)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType)) request.ContentType = contentType;

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body)) using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream)) { writer.Write(body); }

            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetContent(this Uri url)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            using (client)
            {
                client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                return client.DownloadString(url);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            return "";
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Dispose();
            client = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

please note that `.aspx` file extension design the server-side page and in consequence you will be able to download only the html page that display when you navigate on these sites (this is the same for `.php` files).

but if you want to download the frontend view this should work :

```
using System.Net;
...
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("Your url","download location");
```